# xamarin Google maps are not working

Tags: android, xamarin, maps

I am using Xamarin trial version to setup basic map screen on Activity. I have tried many examples avaialble on internet but no luck..

myClass:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Maps;

namespace GoogleMapTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "GoogleMapTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class GoogleMapActivity : Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            var fragTx = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            var mapFragment = Android.Gms.Maps.SupportMapFragment.NewInstance();
            fragTx.Add(Resource.Id.mapView, mapFragment, "mapView");
            fragTx.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/mapView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:longClickable="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/textLayout"
          android:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any matter related to trial account.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the docs?  Using Google maps requires an API key.  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/

Comment: Yes Jason.. I have API key in my code and as well as I am registering SHA1 and package details with API.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have specified the google API key so the Map control can pick it up and do the API calls to Google services.

You would need to follow google's sample for it. Is pretty straightforward.

As with all mobile development for Xamarin, there is still plenty of platform specific work, you need to understand the bits and pieces of the platform you develop for.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I would like to inform you, I had spent around more than 3 days on it.. more than 10 tutorials almost 20 examples I'd tested but none of them work for me. my question remain unanswered.. Is anything belongs to trail account. Do I need indie account to use this feature..